# Xamarin.UWP paragraph full justification partially working

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have installed the latest Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.617.
For a page with multiple breaks in one paragraph element, only the last section is fully justified and all the earlier sections are left justified. This is not so in earlier Xamarin.Forms.

[image]

Comment: Hi , could you share the part code of this  ? Then I will check that in my local site .

Comment: Basically, in my custom renderer for Xamarin.Forms Label, I have the following codes.

RichTextBlock _label = new RichTextBlock();
Run newrun = new Run()
{
  Text = "Some long text" + Environment.NewLine + "Another long text" + Environment.NewLine,
  FontSize = 16,
};
paragraph = new Paragraph()
{
  Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
  TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Justify
};
paragraph.Inlines.Add(newrun);
_label.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! Sorry for not understanding too much about code . If it's a renderer code , you can share the full code of that . That will be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.  The TextAlignment.Left is default and I failed to set some of the paragraphs to TextAlignment.Justify.